# Can i use multiple .sty files

Tags: packages

I wanted to ask if it would be possible to use multiple `.sty` files to declare every specific part in its own file for separation of layout.

Or is this not good or not possible?

I mean for example:

`metadata.sty` => where I will put my newcommands for title, author, university etc.

then `sections.sty` => where I put layout etc and then include them all in my `main.tex` file.

is this possible or not? or what would you suggest for multiple layout files?

thanks already :)

Comment: yes of course look at any example latex file and you will see more than one `\usepackage` line.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I bet you are rep capped by now. If not, i bet answering this will get you some rep points and quite likely also a nice answer badge. ;-) Almost forgot necromancer and the other zombie medal.

Answer (score 5):

Yes of course look at any example latex file and you will see more than one `\usepackage` line.  Typically the definitions in each package have global scope for the whole document but there is nothing stopping you structuring the package usage so that one package defines the document frontmatter commands, and another defines section heading layout, etc.

Comment: what you say is true, but i find the question unclear as to *where* the different packages are to be specified.  they must all be specified in the preamble, not associated with the different sections.

Comment: I have multiple *sty's that constitute "boilerplate" to other sty'.  Could you recommend a way to aggregate these into one sty, but using separate source files for each?